# how to replace text inside span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, replacewith

I have a span like this:

```
<span class="savings">92% sale</span>
```

And I want to change the content inside the span with `"25% sale".`

I'm trying this:

```
$("span.savings").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("", "25% sale"); 
});
```

But this method adds the "25% sale" near the "92% sale".

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `return "25% sale";`

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex `\d{2}` to select 2 digit number

```js
$("span.savings").text(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/\d{2}/, "25");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="savings">92% sale</span>
```

**UPDATE :** If you just want to replace entire text, then there is no need for the callback. Just set the first parameter as the new text.

```js
$("span.savings").text("25% sale");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="savings">92% sale</span>
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the 92 with 25 because on some products I might have 75. I want to remove all the text and change it with mine.

Comment: @agis So, actually your question is "how to change text within element in jQuery" which is *(many times)* duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

See the other answers for a jquery-specific way. If you don't need jquery you can do this (not safe for very old browsers):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("span")
        .getElementsByClassName("savings")
        .forEach(function(el) { el.textContent = "25% sale" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to simply get value, replace text and set it back.

```js
var o = $("span.savings");
o.text(o.text().replace("92", "25"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="savings">92% sale</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
<span class="savings">92% sale</span>
<script>
    $("span.savings").text(function (i, v) {
        return v.replace("92", "25");
    });
</script>
```